# How to fix no module found error in running Django Test

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I am trying to run some simple tests for my blog app. I installed social_django beacsue I want users to be  able to sign in with either their Facebook, Twitter or Google Account.

On running my test using `python manage.py test` I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_fr  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute   
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 143, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.test.TestCase' isn't a subclass of AppConfig.
PS C:\Semicolon\Software Engineering\Web Development\Back End\Django Projects\christian_blog\christian_blog> ^C
PS C:\Semicolon\Software Engineering\Web Development\Back End\Django Projects\christian_blog\christian_blog> python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute   
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social_django'
```

Here is my test code. I am using the default tests.py file created in my 'app'.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from christian_blog_app.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from christian_blog.settings import social_django, crispy_forms, coverage, social_login

# Create your tests here.

class PostTest(TestCase):

    def create_post(self, title="only a test", body="Testing if the created title matches the expected title"):
        return Post.objects.create(title=title, body=body, created_at=timezone.now())

    def test_post_creation(self):
        w = self.create_post()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(w, Post))
        self.assertEqual(w.__str__(), w.title)
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: What does your settings.py look like?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'christian_blog_app',
    'contacts',
    'social_django',
    'social_login',
    'crispy_forms',
    'coverage',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Answer (score 0):

I had to install social_django and some other apps again. It fixed the problem.